# compiling with clang and plugin

Tags: c++, plugins, clang, llvm

`clang` supports plugins, and often this concept is used to build tools like static analysis and such.
To start playing with it I took [this example](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/examples/PrintFunctionNames/PrintFunctionNames.cpp?view=markup) which prints all function names present in the target cpp file(s).
I compiled the plugin running the following:

```
clang++ -v -std=c++11 PrintFunctionNames.cpp \
 $(llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags) \
 -o plugin.so -shared -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup
```

and then run it "by the book":

```
clang++ \
 -c main.cpp \
 -Xclang -load \
 -Xclang $PWD/plugin.so \
 -Xclang -plugin \
 -Xclang print-fns
```

it works just fine: it prints the function names in main.cpp
and exit (without compiling main.cpp due the -c flag).

What I'd like to do is to print all the function names AND compile main.cpp into an executable.
I tried removing the `-c` flag but I got:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /tmp/main-284664.o: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use -add-plugin instead of -plugin

Answer (score 3):

I always thought it "natural" to run `clang` twice, but it is a valid question.

I don't think you are doing anything wrong, but I believe (didn't dig too much into `clang` sources) what is happening is that all `Xclang` are forwarded to the `cc1` [part](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangPlugins.html#using-the-cc1-command-line) of `clang` which create temp files to accommodate the plugin runs. However, when the linker is evoked as a separate process those files are not there anymore, hence the error.
You can see all that by using `-v` option on all those commands.

I'm not sure if this possible, but this SO [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941882/changing-the-source-code-with-a-clang-plugin) might provide a clue to the right direction.

Comment: The link to "this SO thread" is broken. Any chance you still have it?

Comment: @mrks link fixed